# Show $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{a}{n}\cos(\frac{ka}{n})=\frac{\frac{a}{2n}}{\sin(\frac{a}{2n})}\sin(a+\frac{a}{2n})-\frac{a}{2n} $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, summation

I already got the worst part figured out through a proof using the complex definition of sine, I got

$$ \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{a}{n}\cos(\frac{ka}{n})= \frac{a}{n}(\frac{\sin(n+\frac{1}{2})\frac{a}{n}}{2\sin(\frac{a}{2n})}-\frac{1}{2})$$
and have proved that, so I now only need:

$$\frac{a}{n}(\frac{\sin(n+\frac{1}{2})\frac{a}{n}}{2\sin(\frac{a}{2n})}-\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{\frac{a}{2n}}{\sin(\frac{a}{2n})}\sin(a+\frac{a}{2n})-\frac{a}{2n}$$

**Yet, I can't see how they're equal, especially how $\sin(n+\frac{1}{2})$ was modified, I believe I'm missing some trig identity/formula**

Note that I'm tagging this as real analysis, because this is a Riemann Sum of the Integral $\int_{0}^{a}\cos(x)dx$

Comment: In your last equation, do you mean $\sin (n+ \frac{1}{2}) \frac{a}{n}$ or $\sin ((n + \frac{1}{2}) \frac{a}{n})$ (which equals $\sin (a + \frac{a}{n})$)?

Comment: The proof result in the book says $\sin(n+\frac{1}{2})\frac{a}{n}$, but it seems like they meant $\sin((n+\frac{1}{2})\frac{a}{n})$. That has to be the most confusing use of braces in a function argument ever

Comment: If that's a typo, then the last equation is trivial.

Comment: It is, but it seemed so clear that I didn't consider it being a typo, but it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Connor Harris pointed out with the correct parentheses, the equation is trivial:
$$\frac{a}{n}\left(\frac{\sin\left(\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{a}{n}\right)}{2\sin\left(\frac{a}{2n}\right)}-\frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{\frac{a}{2n}}{\sin\left(\frac{a}{2n}\right)}\sin\left(a+\frac{a}{2n}\right)-\frac{a}{2n}$$

We know $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{sin(\frac{a}{2n})}{\frac{a}{2n}}=1$. Define then an equidistant division $x_k = \frac{ka}{n}$ of the interval with thickness $\frac{a}{n}$ and for the riemann sum let $\xi_k = x_k$. It follows:

$$\int_{0}^{a}\cos(x)dx=\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} {RS}_n = sin(a)$$

$q.e.d.$